# Maven Equinox plugin

Tags: java, maven, osgi, equinox

Is there any plugin available that would integrate maven and equinox runtime.? I want my osgi bundles to be packaged , deployed and run in equinox. I am searching for maven commands to perform the whole controlling operations (build the bundles, package and deploy them).

EDIT #1
Somehow I managed to execute maven pax plugin. When I gave the command mvn install pax:provision I got the following error

```
----------------------------------------------------

 -> Using only arguments from command line
 -> Scan bundles from [C:\Users\661447\Desktop\Prime Workspace\OSGiDmHelloWorldP
rovider\runner\deploy-pom.xml]
 -> Scan bundles from [scan-pom:file:/C:/Users/661447/Desktop/Prime Workspace/OS
GiDmHelloWorldProvider/runner/deploy-pom.xml]
 -> Provision bundle [mvn:OSGiDmHelloWorldProvider/OSGiDmHelloWorldProvider/1.0,
 at default start level, bundle will be started, bundle will be loaded from the
cache]
 -> Provision bundle [mvn:org.apache.felix/org.osgi.core/1.4.0, at default start
 level, bundle will be started, bundle will be loaded from the cache]
 -> Preparing framework [Equinox 3.8.1]
 -> Downloading bundles...
 -> Equinox 3.8.1 : connecting...
         ___
        /  /
       /  / Oops, there has been a problem!
      /  /
     /__/   org.ops4j.pax.runner.platform.PlatformException: [link:classpath:run
ner-links/org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.1.link] could not be downloaded
    ___
   /__/     Use --log=debug to see details.----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PaxRunner](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxrunner/Pax+Runner) can help you to deploy bundles of your Maven project and run Equinox

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.ops4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pax-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
         <framework>equinox</framework>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hello Dmytro Pishchukhin. Thanks for the answer. Could you give me some links of tutorials for making use of pax through maven commands? The pax site is down , hence I cant check it out there

Comment: I managed to execute the code. Even though i am getting an Error. I edited the question with the error i am getting. Please help me out to fix it up.

Comment: https://github.com/dpishchukhin/org.knowhowlab.osgi.workshop2012 - test project with pax runner. to start: build project with "mvn install" and then run it with "mvn -P run -Dosgi.framework=equinox"

Comment: I wrote a platform file as you have said in your blog, and even then the problem remains. Whats the mistake I have done? I have no clue on that.

Comment: Ya.. I have made my proxy settings in maven's config.xml file. I am able to download other jars.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use m2e plugin which will perform all the operation you just mentioned above.You can find it in the eclipse marketplace.

Comment: he is asking for Maven Equinox plugin not maven plugin.